# MongoDB - not in other table (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning to use mongodb. I made 3 collections (User, Enrollment, Courses)

```
User
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------+
| _id                                  | user_id | name   |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------+
| ObjectId("5ee6c0511d0843811413b225") | 1       | John   |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------+
| ObjectId("5ef9e9b11db598099e183319") | 2       | Bob    |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------+

Courses
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| _id                                  | courseID| courseName      |
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| ObjectId("5ef9d1b28e08e1c04ac9530b") | "1111"  | English         |
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| ObjectId("5ef9db2bdd883a3444dd396a") | "2222"  | Algebra 1       |
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| ObjectId("5ef9ea212c72182edf809a52") | "3333"  | World History   |
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| ObjectId("5ee6c0511d0843811413b226") | "4444"  | Algebra 2       |
+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+

Enrollment
+---------+----------+
| user_id | courseID |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | "1111"   |
+---------+----------+
| 2       | "2222"   |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | "2222"   |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | "4444"   |
+---------+----------+
```

Everytime user click on one of the courses will added into enrollment table.
I am able to show the enrolled list for user, but I have no idea how to show courses that have not been enrolled by user.

I would like to know how to show courses that have not been added to enrollment table by user?
I tried to use `user_id: { $ne: 1 }`, but doesn't seem show the correct courses that have not been enrolled.

How to show correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Assuming you know `user_id`, let's say we choose Bob with `user_id: 2`

You can either start with getting all courses from `Course` and filter only courses that the user has not enrolled

```
db.Course.aggregate({
  $lookup: { // "join" with Enrollment
    from: "Enrollment",
    localField: "courseID",
    foreignField: "courseID",
    as: "enrollments"
  },
},
{
  $match: { // only match courses that user_id 2 doesn't exist in list of enrolments
    "enrollments.user_id": {
      $ne: 2
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cwiYjmTcEC0)

Or start with `Enrollment` from a particular `User` and find the courses from `Course`

```
db.Enrollment.aggregate({
  $match: { // find enrolments of user_id 2
    user_id: 2
  }
},
{
  $group: { // combine all courseID into an array
    _id: "$user_id",
    courseIDs: {
      $push: "$courseID"
    }
  }
},
{
  $lookup: { // "join" with Course that is not in the list of enrolments
    from: "Course",
    as: "notEnrolledCourses",
    let: {
      courseIDs: "$courseIDs"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$courseID",
                "$$courseIDs"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/)

Note that above approaches don't have the same output structure, you will have to manipulate the to get to your desired output shape.

Comment: thanks mate. I did similar thing but the return is an object like this `<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000213EFE629A0>` how to show it on the template like flask?

Comment: which library are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: @thamsada.ts I'm using flask_mongoengine

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with python, but since it's returning a cursor, I think you have to wrap it with `list()`

Comment: @thamsada.ts thanks man I did it already. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

With this collection structure:

**Step 1**: Fetch user's enrolled courses list. For eg: user 2's courses: ['2222']

**Step 2**: Use `find` query (`{ courseID: { $nin: ['2222'] } }`) on `Courses` collection to fetch un-enrolled courses list.

However, I'd suggest you to update collection's schema by either of following ways:

- Save enrolled courses Ids in `User` collection in an Array.
- Save Courses in an Array in `Enrollment` collection.

This way, you can eliminate some processing in Step 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Abishek Do you mean like this?  `UserCollection: user_id(int), name(string), enrolled[]` and `enrollmentCollection: courseID(int), courseName(string), users[]`

Comment: @sekti92uk If you don't have extra data to keep in `Enrollment`, like for example `startDate`  using the above structure is more favourable than your structure in the question. You only need the keep the array at one side though, so either `enrolled[]` or `users[]`

Comment: @sekti92uk Yes, I meant like that only. Keeping enrolled array in `UserCollection`. If you do that and don't have any extra fields `Enrolled` Collection. Then you can remove `Enrolled` collection.